# Implicit commutativity of operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In C++, operators can be overloaded. If I have two classes `A` and `B` and for instance I can overload `operator ==` in class `A` for comparison with an instance of `B`:

```
class A {
    // Some attributes, methods
public:
    bool operator ==(const B &b) {
        // Implementation of operator ==
    }
}
```

then I can run code like:

```
A a;
B b;

if(a == b) {
    // Some code
}
```

However, if I write `b == a`, the compiler will look for
`bool operator ==(const A &a)` in class B. If it is not found, is there a default behavior in C++ normalization? Will the compiler, whatever it is, exit on failure or run `bool operator ==(const B &b)` instead?

And even better, if it does not find `operator < ()` in class `B`, will it attempt `operator >=()` in class `A`?

Comment: one could argue if it is a good thing, but in principle `A::operator==(B)` can do something completely different than `B::operator==(A)`.

Comment: also in general `a < b` is not the same as `b >= a`

Comment: `<` implies an ordering, while `>=` also implies an equality, which is a stronger condition.

Comment: Overloading operator == in this case, IMHO, should be considered harmful. Since A and B are different types, a==b should never hold (the code compiles, sure. it is syntactically correct code). Adding a to_A() method to class B would be a better solution, and write code like if(a==b.to_A())...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't do either. There's nothing special about overloaded operators; they're just overloaded functions with funny-looking syntax. So `a == b` in the code above is **nothing more than** a call to `a.operator==(const B&)`.

The reason that `b == a` fails, of course, is that there is no `b.operator==(const A&)` (and, similarly, no global operator).

The usual way to deal with this issue is to have a **global** `operator==` rather than a member: `bool operator==(const A&, const B&)`, and another **global** `operator==` that goes the other way: `bool operator==(const B&, const A&)`; if the comparison is, in fact, symmetric, then the second one can be trivially implemented by calling the first: `bool operator==(const B& b, const A& a) { return a == b; }`.

The same principle applies to `operator<`: it doesn't go the other way, and if you want one that does, you have to write it.

(small print: please ignore -- there is `std::relops` (spell-correction wants to change "relops" to "relapse") that will provide these variants; don't use it; it's far too invaisve.)